# Froala Angularjs adding custom buttons

Tags: angularjs, froala

I'm using the Angular 1 bindings for froala. I'm looking for a way to add a custom button so I can create a save button. I have multiple editors on the page and want each one to have a save button where I can call my own API and send the text in that editor a long with custom data to my API.

I've seen some places suggest

```
$.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('alert', {NAME: 'info'});
```

but when I put that into one of my controllers I get an error saying

> Cannot read property 'DefineIcon' of `undefined`.

Any ideas on how I can get this going in angularjs?

Comment: @georgeawg Come on man.

Answer (score 0):

in AngularJS use the following syntax

**Remove "$"**

Replace

```
$.Froala Editor.DefineIcon ('alert', {NAME: 'info'});
```

for

```
FroalaEditor.DefineIcon ('alert', {NAME: 'info'});
```